# Bitlocker Group Policy for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-8.1

it seems when I try to encrypt my hard drive on Windows 8.1, I get this error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JxyI3GQ.png]

When I check the Group Policy settings on the server, that's what we have, although, it says it's only compatible with Windows 7. Is there a way to make it work with Windows 8.1?

[image]

Comment: [In addition to the answer below](http://serverfault.com/a/659284/118258), I'd advise looking into whether or not you can activate TPM on your hardware.  I'd be shocked if you have hardware that can run Windows 8.1, but doesn't have a TPM.  I just finished a Bitlocker rollout for my corporate overlords, and even our 8 year old laptops we still have kicking around had a compatible TPM module.

Comment: I got a clevo P170EM. In page 59 of the manual there is some taking about TPM. Although nothing in the bios. http://www.manualslib.com/manual/674857/Clevo-P170em.html?page=59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Group Policy on a 2012 R2  that should fix the problem.

Says
"At least Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7"

So should work on any higher.

Comment: We don't have the budget to upgrade to a 2012 license...